# How do you view your YouTube account as another user would see it?

Tags: youtube

Without physically logging out of the site, how do I view my YouTube channel as a member of the public and/or registered user would see it? Is there a native function for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Sign in to your YouTube account on a computer.

On the left, select My channel.

Use the drop-down menu next to your name to view your channel as Yourself, a New visitor, or a Returning subscriber. When you want to go back to viewing as yourself, click Done at the top of the screen.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3027950?hl=en